# Problema com variáveis de ambiente para uma aplicação inexistente

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, iphone, osx

Estou tentando simular uma aplicação nova feito em react-native no IOS, porém após o emulador apresentar meu app, 3 segundos depois abre outro endereço que não tem nada a ver com o diretório do meu app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu achei que poderia ser a configuração do Pod que deve ter feito alguma besteira que salvou de maneira global, ou nas variáveis de ambiente, mas eu já deletei tudo:

`pod deintegrate /User/ivanferrer/projects/arvore_educacao/test/HelloWord`
`pod clear`

Removi a lib: Podfile

E mesmo assim persiste, o que eu faço?

Aqui está o que parece:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-Core" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-DevSupport" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTActionSheet" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTAnimation" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTImage" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTLinking" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTNetwork" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTSettings" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTText" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTVibration" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-RCTWebSocket" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-jsi" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/glog" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/yoga"
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DoubleConversion" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Folly" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-Core" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-DevSupport" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTActionSheet" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTAnimation" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTBlob" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTImage" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTLinking" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTNetwork" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTSettings" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTText" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTVibration" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-RCTWebSocket" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-cxxreact" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-jsi" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-jsiexecutor" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/React-jsinspector" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/glog" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/yoga"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"DoubleConversion" -l"Folly" -l"React-Core" -l"React-DevSupport" -l"React-RCTActionSheet" -l"React-RCTAnimation" -l"React-RCTBlob" -l"React-RCTImage" -l"React-RCTLinking" -l"React-RCTNetwork" -l"React-RCTSettings" -l"React-RCTText" -l"React-RCTVibration" -l"React-RCTWebSocket" -l"React-cxxreact" -l"React-jsi" -l"React-jsiexecutor" -l"React-jsinspector" -l"glog" -l"stdc++" -l"yoga" -framework "JavaScriptCore"
PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui a solução que resolveu o problema:

Apagar o cache do emulador do iOS:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Apagar o cache de build:

```
rm -rf ios/build
```

Inicia o server do react-native sem cache:

```
react-native start -- --reset-cache
```